# Robots.txt disable query parameters scanning with exceptions

Tags: regex, .htaccess, robots.txt

I am implementing some SEO changes including robots.txt changes and I am solving this problem.

I need to disable (or disallow to be precise) every URL that contains some query URL params (?xy=...)
So I have added this rule

```
Disallow: /*?*
```

But there is a small problem. I need to allow specific query params for specific sub URL.
So lets say I need to allow */picture?path=XY*. This **should be allowed** but for example */picture-other?path=XY* **not** so as */picture?other_param=XY* (the /picture is okay but there is no just param named path)

Is it possible to do this in robots.txt?

EDIT:
(Maybe more clear instructions added)

**Disable ALL URLS containing query parameters (like /x?param=1)** but **allow query parameter path on URL /picture**.
So only one allowed URL with query param will be */picture?path=XY* no other URLs containing query parameters will be allowed for robots

Examples

**Allowed**

```
/picture?path=XY
/literally/any/route/without/query/param/you/can/imagine
/home
/
```

**Now allowed**

```
/picture?param=1
literally/any/route/with/query/param/you/can/imagine?param=1
/some/other/url?query=5&param=1
/some/other/route/with/path/param?path=XY
```

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about **SEO** which is off-topic at Stack Overflow. Please read ["Which SEO questions should be closed as non-programming/non-admin?"](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/382618) to better understand when SEO questions are acceptable to ask here (most are not) and where you might be able to get assistance.

Comment: @JohnConde Hello, yea I´ve been thinking if its the proper question here on SO and It it mostly about to write the proper regular expression which is here on SO common thing to ask. but if I have misunderstood the rules I can move this question to Webmasters SE

Comment: @Joel thats the problem, I want to disallow ALL URL containing query params exept one specific URL containing one specific query param.

Comment: [Can we use regex in robots.txt file to block URLs?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/72722/can-we-use-regex-in-robots-txt-file-to-block-urls)

Comment: Also make sure what you are trying to do requires robots.txt or do you really mean `X-Robots-Tag`

Comment: I have editted the question. I hope instructions are more clear now.

Comment: @Joel I have added some examples. If its still unclear I do not know how to explain myself more precisely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Disallowed paths** you provided:

```
/picture?param=1
literally/any/route/with/query/param/you/can/imagine?param=1
/some/other/url?query=5&param=1
/some/other/route/with/path/param?path=XY
```

Robots:

```
Allow: /*
Disallow: /picture?param=*$
Disallow: *param?*
Disallow: *param=*
```

Regex supported by most (*if not all*) search-engines:

`*` - wildcard

`$` - end of URL (string)

So if you want to disallow all urls containing `param` just wrap `*` around it.

## Update:

```
Allow: /picture?*
Disallow: *?*=*
Disallow: *?*=*&*=*
Disallow: *?*=*=*
```

Will Block:

```
http://my-domain.com/test?xwadwa=1
http://my-domain.com/dwa?query=1
http://my-domain.com/test?dwadwa=1
http://my-domain.com/test?dwadwa=1&zxxxa=1
http://my-domain.com/test/dwa/dwa/dwa/dwa/dwa/dwa?xxxx=1
```

But will allow:

```
http://my-domain.com/picture?everything_after_this_point
http://my-domain.com/picture?everything_after_this_point&query=32131
http://my-domain.com/
http://my-domain.com/test/
http://my-domain.com/test/test/
http://my-domain.com/test/test/test/
http://my-domain.com/test/test/test/test
```

Comment: There param names can be anything, thats why i have written 2 query params in disallow example (for now for example just param but in the future they can be added some other filter methods - some new product information people want to filter products by - and in that time these robots wont work. I need to block literally ANY query param given exept query param *path* on /picture URL

Comment: Yea, thats kinda what I want but I was not sure that if i use rules like you have written (or rule I have written in my original question - that will disaalow all params in URL) that these Allow rule will work (that previous rule disabling all params would not override the allow rule)

Comment: Yep, thats exactly what I want. Thank you so much for your help.